# LinkedHashMap и внутреннее устройство

Tags: java, коллекции, терминология

Почему говорят, что `LinkedHashMap` это хеш-таблица + `LinkedList`, если в исходниках в идее смотрю, внутри `LinkedHashMap` нет `LinkedList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Там не используется `LinkedList` напрямую, речь больше про концептуальную схожесть. В частности, посмотрите на эту [строку](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#L443) в исходниках.

```
void createEntry(int hash, K key, V value, int bucketIndex) {
    // ...
    e.addBefore(header);
    // ...
}
```

Вот именно `e.addBefore(header);` внутри перелинковывает элементы:

```
private void addBefore(Entry<K,V> existingEntry) {
    after  = existingEntry;
    before = existingEntry.before;
    before.after = this;
    after.before = this;
}
```

Это похоже на перелинковку элементов в `LinkedList`, поэтому так и называют.

Comment: Прекрасный ответ, надеюсь будете хорошим и активным модератором!

Comment: Через 4 минуты смогу принять ответ

Comment: @АлександрКапцов всегда рад помочь)